# I want to set the port in the API from Heroku in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, port

I am deploying Node and React app on Heroku at the same server, I have set up my Axios in React with base URL like this:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:5001/api`,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

Because Heroku creates a dynamic port for my Node app, this is not working to make request. Is there is any way I can read the port generated by Heroku and use it my React app?

Comment: That makes no sense. You don't need to know the port _outside_ Heroku, you just use the URL. The React client code isn't running on Heroku at all, it's running on your users' browsers - it can't access anything via localhost. You'd be better with _relative_ endpoints, e.g. as I've set up in https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit

Comment: which folder on that repo I can find this in it @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is deployed on heroku, why are you trying to use a url including localhost instead of the url of your app that heroku provides you?

Anyway, I think you can retrieve the port that heroku is using with `process.env.PORT`

Comment: yes that's correct I used the URL provided by heroku and this solve my issue ,I tried to read the port with the way you mentioned in  React app but it gave me undefined
thanks @liguepk

Comment: Weird, I have a node.js app on heroku that reads the heroku port using `process.env.PORT` ... Anyway, if this answer suits you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: in the just nodeJS app it will read it but in reactJS app it will not